# Do Spot devices have a sleep mode?

Tags: gear

I’ve purchased a SpotX device and noticed that the screen never turns off. I’ve tried using the menu or pressing the power button but there’s only an option for Power Off, not Sleep.

(Spot questions are okay as per [Would some questions on Spot Personal tracker be good?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113/would-some-questions-on-spot-personal-tracker-be-good))

Comment: I can't find a definitive answer, but the screen looks like e-ink, which takes no power to maintain (like a Kindle).  If that's the case it could be sleeping most of the time and you wouldn't even know.  As you have one, you can test what happens to the screen when you take the batteries out (I think they're removable).  Power off may blank the screen anyway, so you know not to try and interact with it.  Even B&W LCDs use very little power to maintain their image

Comment: Why not ask GlobalStar directly? This is a yes/no question.

Comment: @Gabriel even if I do ask them eventually it would be convenient to have the answer available via a quick Google search.

Comment: @JonathanReez  The guidelines for asking questions suggest the OP should do his own research beforehand and come here if the problem cannot be solved. You obviously haven't, so I fail to see how helpful this question is.

Comment: @Gabriel “research beforehand” means “Google it”. It doesn’t mean “contact the manufacturer”.

Comment: @JonathanReez In what world does doing research on a device not include looking at their FAQ, reading the manual, and contacting the device manufacturer and provider of service? (BTW, I did one of these and found your answer in 2 minutes)

Comment: @Gabriel care to post an answer?

Comment: https://www.findmespot.com/en-us/support/spot-x/get-help/hardware/does-the-spotx-turn-off-if-it-s-idle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their FAQ](https://www.findmespot.com/en-us/support/spot-x/get-help/hardware/does-the-spotx-turn-off-if-it-s-idle):

> Does the SPOT X turn off if it's idle?
>
> No, the device does not need to turn off to save battery. The SPOT X
> uses technology which allows it to use very little power when not
> actively sending messages or navigating.

So there is no "sleep" mode on Spot X.